# Pivot Table - data summed in two columns with different criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that summarizes Sales per Customer. The data set has month indicator for each transaction.

I would like to get the pivot table to have two columns - one for 12 months of 2018; and the other one for "randomly selected" 12 months. To be able to compare eg previous year to rolling 12 months.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks

edit1:
Screen shot - Data in grey, pivot-table should provide data organized like mini table on the right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4YmV.jpg)

Luka

Comment: Could you provide a sample or screenshot about this problem?

Comment: hi Lee, I have eddied the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add each field as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have about 1,2m rows, and add cca 100k every month; so it is a bit to much for Excel to handle